# Remove a part of a path from a variable content

Tags: bash, shell, filenames, string

In a Bash I have a variable:

```
LOCAL_PATH="/this/is/a/path/"
```

Then I have another variable, which content starts with LOCAL_PATH and it should be removed:

```
LINE="/this/is/a/path/which/is/longer"
```

The result should be:

```
RESULT="which/is/longer"
```

I have tried it with the String manipulation of the Bash

```
RESULT=$(echo "${LINE//\/this\/is\/a\/path\/}")
```

But how I can include the variable LOCAL_PATH there to prevent the hard-coded path in the expression above?

Answer (score 2):

Just include `LOCAL_PATH` in pattern part:

```
printf '%s\n' "${LINE//"$LOCAL_PATH"/}"
```

If `LINE` always start with content of `LOCAL_PATH`, POSIXly:

```
printf '%s\n' "${LINE#"$LOCAL_PATH"}"
```

Comment: @Gilles: It doesn't. `a='/*/*/*/*/../../../../*/*/*/*/../../../../*/*/*/*'; echo "${b//$a/}"` work well.

Comment: Your first example will remove the `local_part` any place it happens. To remove it only at the beggining (with that idiom ) use: `printf '%s\n' "${LINE/#"$LOCAL_PATH"/}".

Comment: @BinaryZebra: Ah right, I was confused, it's pattern matching matter, not filename expansion or fields splitting.